# Freezes javafx undecorated window

Tags: javafx

Good day. I have been trying to make a transparent, undecorated resizable window,with the same behavior as the usual window. I'm facing a problem, when changing a size of my window appear a  freezes and shake the window contents and bounds.

Below is my code showing this problem, right pane (borderPaneR) has not immediately accept the changes, freezes when have been changing size of  window. Can you tell how it solve.

```
public class DemoBehaviorProblem extends Application {
double initX;
double windowX;
double windowWidth;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    // Create window's elements
    Pane borderPaneL = new Pane();
    borderPaneL.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(85, 255, 0, 0.5); -fx-cursor: w-resize;");
    Pane borderPaneR = new Pane();
    borderPaneR.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(85, 255, 0, 0.5); -fx-cursor: e-resize;");
    Pane root = new Pane(borderPaneL, borderPaneR);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300, new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.5));

    // Set up side panes
    final int BORDER_WIDTH = 8;
    borderPaneL.setPrefWidth(BORDER_WIDTH);
    borderPaneL.setPrefHeight(scene.getHeight());

    borderPaneR.setLayoutX(scene.getWidth() - BORDER_WIDTH);
    borderPaneR.setPrefWidth(BORDER_WIDTH);
    borderPaneR.setPrefHeight(scene.getHeight());

    //User content
    VBox content = new VBox();
    content.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(255, 230, 0, 0.5); -fx-pref-width: 336; -fx-pref-height: 284;");
    content.setLayoutX(BORDER_WIDTH * 4);
    content.setLayoutY(BORDER_WIDTH);
    root.widthProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> content.setPrefWidth(newValue.doubleValue() - 8*BORDER_WIDTH)));
    root.getChildren().add(content);

    // Showing window
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    // Set up resizable behavior

    // When changed width of stage, change position of right pane
    stage.widthProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        borderPaneR.setLayoutX(newValue.doubleValue() - BORDER_WIDTH);
    });

    // Moving a left bound
    borderPaneL.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, event -> {
        if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
            initX = event.getScreenX();
            windowX = stage.getX();
            windowWidth = windowX + stage.getWidth();
        }

        if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
            double deltaX = event.getScreenX() - initX;
            stage.setX(windowX + deltaX);
            stage.setWidth(windowWidth - windowX - deltaX);
        }
    });

    // Moving a right bound
    borderPaneR.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.ANY, event -> {
        if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED) {
            initX = event.getSceneX();
            windowWidth = stage.getWidth();
        }

        if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
            double deltaX = event.getSceneX() - initX;
            stage.setWidth(windowWidth + deltaX);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Your code is running for me and i did not find any freeze.

Comment: Are you sure? Freezes appear when changing size of window. For it do need to dragged left edge of window with mouse cursor, in this moment the bound of right side is freezes and shakes. Pay attention on a 'borderPaneR' and right side of 'VBox' (named "content").

Comment: Some jitter if you resize it on the left size, but no freezes to be seen.